# Alternate of on behalf

Tags: meaning-in-context

My friend conveyed his wishes to my mom on her birthday, and asked me to pass them to her on his behalf.

But said like, "Wish her a birthday for me."

Is it correct usage of word? Shouldn't it be "from me"?

Comment: He's using "for me" as in "please do this *for me*" (because I won't be there to do it myself).

Comment: Your question is not related to the example you gave. You may want to edit your question.

Comment: The preposition *for* means *on behalf of*. No. 3 definition of [Oxford Online Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "*for"* relates to his request of you to deliver the best wishes, not to the birthday wish itself.  He is asking you to do this action *for him*, but of course the wish itself, from your mother's perspective, is coming *from him*.

I prefer that construct to the equally correct request to "deliver a birthday best wish from me" as I am showing that I appreciate your delivering the message rather than making the focus on my wish delivery with your action being the implied part of the sentence. I would generally only use the "from" construct if I wanted you to pass on a wish from a larger group than just me. "Please wish her a happy birthday from me and my wife."

Answer (score 1):

"For me" as in, "instead of me".  "From me" would be correct as well, and it's really just a matter of taste.